# Question regarding pseudocode of the Simplex algorithm

Tags: optimization, algorithms, simplex-method

In class I learned the following pseudocode for the simplex algorithm:[image]

However, what is unclear to me about this procedute is the "solve" command in lines 3 and 8. When solving $A_B^Ty = c_B$, do the matrix $A_B^T, c_B$ need to be changed too, i.e. do the row transformations done in the Gauss algorithm used to solve $A_B^Ty = c_B$ carry over to the whole algorithm? Could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given $B$, in the simplex method we have that $A_B$ is invertible. So in this case we are solving for $y$ via $y = A_B^{-1}c_B$. Then we update $B$ later in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous answer, the linear system solving problem can be solved using LU decomposition ([LU Decomposition for Solving Linear Equations](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/cs357/sp2020/notes/ref-9-linsys.html)
) or other methods (as shown in [MATLAB mldivide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUenQ.png)) to get better speed. By the way, in your pseudocode (line 4), solving for $u = c - A^T y$ and then getting $u_N = u[N]$ is faster than solving for $u_N = c_N - A^T_N y$ when implemented using code like Python. However your pseudocode is very clean and concise, can I know which book it came from?